# Remove multiple firebase listeners at once

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating an app with react native and face the problem that I create multiple firebase listeners troughout the app, listeners on different screens to be precise and also listeners that listen to the `firebase-database` and others listening to the `firestore`.

What I want to accomplish is to kill all those listeners with one call or if necessary with multiple lines but as compact as possible - and also **from an entire different screen where the listeners arent even running**, this is important.

I know that there is the possibility to use `Firebase.goOffline()` but this only disconnects me from the Firebase - **it doesnt stop the listeners**. As soon as I `goOnline()` again, the listeners are all back.

I didnt find any solution yet for this problem from google etc thats why I try to ask here now, I would appriciate if anybody would have an idea how maybe an approach how to handle this type of behavior.

The following code samples provide you with listeners I included inside my app, they are located in in the same screen but I have nearly identical ones in other screens.

**Database listener:**

```
const statusListener = () => {
        var partnerRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${partnerId}/onlineState`);
        partnerRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
            setPartnerState(snapshot.val())
        })
    };
```

**Firestore Listener:** (this one is very long, thats only because I filter the documents I retrieve from the listener)

```
const loadnewmessages = () =>{ firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).orderBy("timestamp").limit(50).onSnapshot((snapshot)  => {
            var newmessages = [];
            var deletedmesssages = [];
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                if(change.type  === "added"){
                    newmessages.push({
                        counter: change.doc.data().counter,
                        sender: change.doc.data().sender,
                        timestamp: change.doc.data().timestamp.toString(),
                        value: change.doc.data().value,
                        displayedTime: new Date(change.doc.data().displayedTime)
                    })
                };
                if(change.type  === "removed"){
                    deletedmesssages.push({
                        counter: change.doc.data().counter,
                        sender: change.doc.data().sender,
                        timestamp: change.doc.data().timestamp.toString(),
                        value: change.doc.data().value,
                        displayedTime: new Date(change.doc.data().displayedTime)
                    })
                };

            })
            if(newmessages.length > 0){
                setChatMessages(chatmessages => {
                    return chatmessages.concat(newmessages)
                });
            };
            if(deletedmesssages.length > 0){
                setChatMessages(chatmessages => {
                    var modifythisarray = chatmessages;
                    let index = chatmessages.map(e => e.timestamp).indexOf(`${deletedmesssages[0].timestamp}`);
                    let pasttime = Date.now() - parseInt(modifythisarray[index].timestamp);
                    modifythisarray.splice(index, 1);
                    if(pasttime > 300000){
                        return chatmessages
                    }else{
                        return modifythisarray
                    }
                });
                setRefreshFlatList(refreshFlatlist => {
                    //console.log("Aktueller Status von refresher: ", refreshFlatlist);
                    return !refreshFlatlist
                });
            }
            newmessages = [];
            deletedmesssages = [];
        })
    };
```

**Both those listeners are called within a useEffect hook just like that:** (useEffect with empty braces at the end makes sure those listeners are called only once and not multiple times.)

```
useEffect(() => {
        loadnewmessages();
        statusListener();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Can you add some code to detail how you are registering the listeners?

Comment: @DanielDuong sure thing, I just added two examples! One listener attached to the database and one to the firestore.

Comment: There is no shorthand here: you'll need to track the listeners and remove them as shown in the documentation for both products ([Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners)).

Comment: But what if I have my listeners on one chatscreen and I want to logoff the user from another screen component? I wont have any access to both of the listeners. I would need to stop the listener as soon as I leave the chat screen. As soon as I come back to the screen the listener reactivates and downloads all 2o files again, making my bills expensive because first time the listener goes online it downloads all 20 recent created files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the subscribe functions return the unsubscribe function

```
const unSubscriptions = [];

... Where you subscribe
const unSub = document.onSnapshot(listener);
subscriptions.push(unSub);

... Where you unsubscribe all
function unSubAll () {
   unSubscriptions.forEach((unSub) => unSub());
   // Clear the array
   unSubscriptions.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but there is one problem! 
Depending on if its a firestore or database listener, you need to stop them differently. Database uses .off() and with firestore you need to do it like you did above. Your solution basicly only applies to firestore listeners only :)

Comment: Remember that in javascript, functions are first class citizens. So instead of calling off. You can push it to the unSubscriptions array.
     unSubscriptions.push(databaseRef.off);